# jquery append content from iframe

Tags: jquery, append

I would like to transfer some content from (div class="StaffBlock") that loaded from the iframe from /index.html into div class="Contact-Agent-Append". but my jquery is not working and i dont know why, is it because of im loading it from iframe? Thanks.

```
<iframe scrolling="no" height="60px" frameborder="0" width="150px" src="/index.html" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" style="overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0; display: none;"></iframe>

<script>
$('.StaffBlock').appendTo($('.Contact-Agent-Append'));
</script> 

<div class="Contact-Agent-Append">content should go here
</div>
```

### **Question Updated:**

**this is the content stored in the remote url which contain the StaffBlock:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/StyleSheets/listing-contact.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="listing-contact">
<div class="StaffBlock">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="col-a">{tag_name}</td>
    <td class="col-b" rowspan="4">{tag_Staff Photo}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{tag_job title}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{tag_mobile}</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="mailto:{tag_email}">email me</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**and this is the original coding that contain the iframe:**

```
<div class="Contact-Agent-{tag_Publish As Agent}">

    <div class="Contact-Agent-Small-Logo-listing" title="this property is published by agent">
    </div>
    <iframe scrolling="no" height="60px" frameborder="0" width="150px" src="{tag_listing agent staff url}" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" style="overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0; display: none;"></iframe>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('iframe').contents().find('.StaffBlock').clone().appendTo($('.Contact-Agent-Append'))‌​‌​
});//]]>  
    </script> 
    <div class="Contact-Agent-Append">1
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into account that you have to **wait until both the page and the iframe are ready for DOM manipulation**. Using one `$(document).ready()` is not enough.

In your case, it seems you can modify the content of your iframe. I'd suggest **using the iframe to push data into the main page**, instead of getting data from it, it will make sure both are ready.

You will probably need to load jQuery in your iframe, the great thing is that you can **add a parameter to your selectors to change its context**. Default is document, but in your case you will need to target the main page from the iframe document.

Also do not forget that if you want the content of a div, a selector is not enough. Either use its `.html()` or `.clone()` it.

```
// in your iframe :
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.Contact-Agent-Append', window.parent.document)
    // or window.parent.$('.Contact-Agent-Append')
        .append( $('.StaffBlock').html() );
});
```

You might want to adapt the selector based on your needs, but it will work faster than a setInterval. If at first it doesn't work try removing jQuery from the mainpage to prevent any conflict, if it solves your issue try using [`j=jQuery.noConflict();`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" scrolling="no" height="60px" frameborder="0" width="150px" src="/index.html" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" style="overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0; display: none;"></iframe>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#iframe1').each(function() {
       $('.Contact-Agent-Append').append($('div.StaffBlock',this.contentWindow.document||this.contentDocument).html() );
    })
});
```

This assumes that the iframe source is on the same domain.

Comment: nope, still not working. here is my original iframe:  <iframe scrolling="no" height="60px" frameborder="0" width="150px" src="{tag_listing agent staff url}" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" style="overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0; display: none;"></iframe>

Comment: Also make sure you are doing all of this after the document is loaded.

Comment: there is no any error, but what supposed to show is not showing

Answer (score 0):

```
             $(window).load(function(){
var flag=true;
          var id= setInterval(function(){if(typeof($('iframe').contents().find('body.StaffBlock').html())!='undefined')
               {
if(flag){
$('.Contact-Agent-Append').append( $('iframe').contents().find('body.StaffBlock').clone())‌​‌​; 
}
flag=false;
        }

    },500);
            });
```

Comment: Hi Ashivad, thanks for your code, it works, but the problem is it repeated 20 times of the StaffBlock

Comment: nope, not working. the code is working but with 20 times repeat is:     <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('iframe').contents().find('.StaffBlock').clone().appendTo($('.Contact-Agent-Append'))
    });//]]>
    </script>